# Weird case with data tables in R, column names are mixed

Tags: r, datatable

So I have created this variable that is called `mc_split_device` inside the datatable called `mc_with_devices`. However, If I type `mc_with_devices$mc_split` I get the values of the column `mc_split_device` while I never created any variable with the name `mc_split`.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [Hadley Wickham's Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html#subsetting-operators):

> $ is a shorthand operator, where x$y is equivalent to x[["y", exact = FALSE]]. It’s often used to access variables in a data frame, as in mtcars$cyl or diamonds$carat.

So the `exact=FALSE` is the reason why `$mc_split` works despite there not being a column with that exact name.

As an aside, I don't believe `mc_with_devices[,.(mc_split)]` will work without doublequotes. The following will work:

`mc_with_devices[,"mc_split_resp"]`

Answer (score 5):

It matches the name of the column partially. From `?Extract`

> names : For extraction, this is normally (see under ‘Environments’) partially matched to the names of the object.
>
> Character indices can in some circumstances be partially matched (see pmatch) to the names or dimnames of the object being subsetted
>
> Thus the default behaviour is to use partial matching only when extracting from recursive objects (except environments) by $.

Hence, when you do

```
mtcars$m
```

You get

```
#[1] 21.0 21.0 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 17.8 16.4 17.3 15.2 10.4 10.4
#[17] 14.7 32.4 30.4 33.9 21.5 15.5 15.2 13.3 19.2 27.3 26.0 30.4 15.8 19.7 15.0 21.4
```

which is same as `mtcars$mpg`

This can be sometimes confusing and if you want to make sure to be notified when such partial matching is done. You can turn on the warning by

```
options(warnPartialMatchDollar = TRUE)
mtcars$m
# [1] 21.0 21.0 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 17.8 16.4 17.3 15.2 10.4 10.4
#[17] 14.7 32.4 30.4 33.9 21.5 15.5 15.2 13.3 19.2 27.3 26.0 30.4 15.8 19.7 15.0 21.4
```

> Warning message:
>   In `$.data.frame`(mtcars, m) : Partial match of 'm' to 'mpg' in data frame

Answer (score 0):

According to `?Extract`

> name - A literal character string or a name (possibly backtick quoted). For extraction, this is normally (see under ‘Environments’) partially matched to the names of the object.

and `exact`

> exact - Controls possible partial matching of [[ when extracting by a character vector (for most objects, but see under ‘Environments’). The default is no partial matching. Value NA allows partial matching but issues a warning when it occurs. Value FALSE allows partial matching without any warning.

So, when we do

```
mtcars$m
#[1] 21.0 21.0 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 17.8 16.4 17.3 15.2 10.4 10.4 14.7 32.4 30.4 33.9 21.5 15.5 15.2 13.3 19.2 27.3
#[27] 26.0 30.4 15.8 19.7 15.0 21.4

mtcars$d
#NULL
```

Because there are multiple names that starts with 'd'

```
 names(mtcars)
 #[1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear" "carb"
```

If we are specific, it does the partial match for the 'disp' column

```
mtcars$di
#[1] 160.0 160.0 108.0 258.0 360.0 225.0 360.0 146.7 140.8 167.6 167.6 275.8 275.8 275.8 472.0 460.0 440.0  78.7  75.7  71.1 120.1
#[22] 318.0 304.0 350.0 400.0  79.0 120.3  95.1 351.0 145.0 301.0 121.0
```